# Delay Activity is not working - Is this fixed in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, bug

I have a sequential workflow with some DelayActivities in it which do not work (most of the time). Once the time elapses they don't fire and workflow just waits forever.

Found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/9f5784de-b666-4dbc-8cea-ce9d5c221f2d/) after searching the web and seems there is a [hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21066), so...

... **problem revisited**: it's 2012, on a Windows 7 x64 PC, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, SharePoint 2010, all the dlls mentioned in the hotfix (i.e. System.workflow.activities.dll, System.workflow.componentmodel.dll, System.workflow.runtime.dll) are version 3.0.0.0 in my GAC instead of 3.0.4203.201.

Is it the same cause? Does the hotfix work for Windows 7? Does it even work?

What is the correct solution for fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse the version number shown when you go to the GAC with the file version. The version number shown is the AssemblyVersion which is used when clients specify which version they want to load.

The file version specified in the kb article is the version of this dll implementing a certain assembly version. To see the file version of an assembly in the gac right click and select properties it's then shown on the Version tab:
[image]

In fact each assembly also have a third version number Product Version. File version and Product version are both only informational. Whereas AssemblyVersion has impact on clients loading assembly, this is why AssemblyVersion is only updated when you want to store more than one version in GAC.

Comment: So that means it's fixed :D?

Comment: My RTM SharePoint foundation has System.Workflow.Runtime.dll as 3.0.4203.4037, so it seems that the mentioned patch is already on it, but I can't tell if this due to it being Windows Server 2008.